# Ubuntu no longer updates saying it can't be done securely since it's no longer signed

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

`Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

See the errors below. I can no longer update my repos or install new packages. Every repo is saying that it is no longer signed. This only started happening yesterday and it was working in the morning as I always look for updates in the morning. I noticed the issue when I needed to install an application and started getting these errors.

Update:

```
sudo apt update
Err:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/focal-pgdg/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Install:

```
sudo apt install lynx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libidn11 lynx-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libidn11 lynx lynx-common
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1586 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5731 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libidn11 amd64 1.33-2.2ubuntu2
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 lynx-common all 2.9.0dev.5-1
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 lynx amd64 2.9.0dev.5-1
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 lynx-common all 2.9.0dev.5-1
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.33-2.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lynx/lynx-common_2.9.0dev.5-1_all.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lynx/lynx_2.9.0dev.5-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Both `update` and `install` are getting `400 Bad Request` errors with `update` showing the repo is no longer signed. As far as I'm aware, Ubuntu 20.04 is still supported and should be up until 2025 (2030 if you count ESM).

Edit:

As per comments, likely time or proxy. Came back from a weekend away and everything is working again. Could have been the NTP server with the time being off. If anyone has this issue I'd check your time and disable any/all proxies.

Comment: I would assume a problem on the server end http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu ends up going to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu etc and I now see a http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/  would have expected  to see release names in there

Comment: @Rinzwind so this is a server issue and something Ubuntu will need to correct?

Comment: I would assume the admin of archive.ubuntu.com whoever that may be ) http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ does exist so pretty odd :P

Comment: Check the clock setting. Make sure it's manually set current or at least within a few minutes If it's off your network may not work then you may not be able to get updates.

Comment: 400 Bad Request on *every* domain you're going to sounds like you have some sort of proxy in line somewhere.    "Bad Request" is not a normal response, and since you get that reply also for a third party PostgreSQL repository it's likely you have some sort of network filtering going on - either a proxy in line that's not working right, or firewall rules from your ISP or provider blocking acess.  This isn't something that needs fixed by the Canonical or Ubuntu side of things, because the issue goes *beyond* just the Ubuntu repos especially when you see the same error for PostgreSQL's repos.

Comment: @quickblueblur - maybe post the details of what you did as an answer to your question?

Comment: @Will I didn't do anything; so I don't think an answer is appropriate since it would just be an assumption (was it time? was it proxy? was it something else?). So I edited the main post to indicate potential areas to check, but without knowing for sure what solved the issue, I can't really answer.